# Canntot be able to switch node version on CENTOS 7

Tags: node.js, centos

I am trying to upgrade node version on Centos7 fron 8.16.0 to 10.16.0.
I am getting like installed 10.16.0 and active as 8.16.0
If I check node version still showing as 8.16.0

Result:
[mani@desktop]$ sudo n 10.16.0
   installed : v10.16.0 to /usr/local/bin/node
      active : v8.16.0 at /bin/node
[mani@desktop]$ 
[mani@desktop]$ node -v
v8.16.0
[mani@desktop]$

Can anyone help me upgrading the node version. Thanks!

Comment: use something like [nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm) for organizing your node versions

Comment: Either install nvm first and manage version using that or uninstall node and install it again.

Answer (score 0):

According to the provided output I think that there are two installed NodeJS instances in the next directories:

```
/usr/local/bin/node
/bin/node
```

Try executing the next commands:

```
/usr/local/bin/node -v
```

And

```
/bin/node -v
```

And see what is the output. It should be different in both cases. Additionally you can understand which node binary the user you are logged as is using with the next command:

```
which node
```

Hope these commands and their output provide you with a bit more information.

Comment: Yes you are correct, it is different in both the cases:  
[Host@~]$ /usr/local/bin/node -v  
v10.16.0  
[Host@~]$ /bin/node -v  
v8.16.0  
[Host@~]$ which node  
/usr/local/bin/node  
How can I fix this?